# Iphone App: Is that possible to set voice message through the app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Let's say, we have an app where we can record the voice message or choose from the ready made voice messages. Once we selected or recorded the voice message and app is active, when someone call the phone and we didn't pick up, can the app turn on the voice message that we set to the caller. Is that possible to do with the current iphone SDK? Can we able to have access to change the voice message through app? Please kindly share your ideas and experiences. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Not possible, that's a carrier function, not on the phone itself.